# Another section numbering format

Tags: sectioning

My current section numbering format is something like this:

> 1
>   1.2
>   1.2,3

But I want it to be like this:

> 1-
>   1-2-
>   1-2-3-

What should I do?

Comment: As I said in a comment to my answer, you have redefined the wrong commands; it is not `\renewcommand\section{\arabic{section}--} \renewcommand\subsection{\section\arabic{subsection}--} \renewcommand\subsubsection{\subsection\arabic{subsubsection}--}` but `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}--} \renewcommand\thesubsection{\section\arabic{subsection}--} \renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\subsection\arabic{subsubsection}--}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Redefine `\thesection`, `\thesubsection` and `\thesubsubsection` (the representation for the counters):

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}--}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}--}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection\arabic{subsubsection}--}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Based on a comment, it seems that the [`bidi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bidi) package is being used; in this case, the change can be made using simply `\SepMark`, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bidi}

% Use either the next line or the \renewcommand lines below
\SepMark{--}

%\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}--}
%\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}--}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is my thesis file, I did this by the codes bellow; but everything went to a simple text. No bold text, etc.  \renewcommand\section{\arabic{section}--}
\renewcommand\subsection{\section\arabic{subsection}--}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\subsection\arabic{subsubsection}--}

Comment: @Parsa Ah, I see the problem; notice that you are redefining the wrong commands; it is not  `\renewcommand\section{\arabic{section}--}` but  `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}--}` (notice the prefix "the" that you omitted in your code) and analogously fot the other commands.

Comment: I used them with 'the' and nothing happened, the output was the same.

Comment: @Parsa No, the output should not be the same. In case it is not working provide a *complete* little test document like the one in my answer (but *complete*, not just useless code snippets) showing the undesired result.

Comment: My TeX code is a little complicated and I am very very basic to work with it. But a friend of mine told me this and workd for the text not in the margins: put \SepMark{-} before ‎\begin{document}‎‎

Comment: @Parsa It seems then that you are using `xelatex` and the `bidi` package (you should have mentioned this in your question). In that case, the redefinitions I suggested must be added *after* loading the package, or you can use `\SepMark` as you mentioned in your comment. I added a remark about this to my answer.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks by the way. You made a huge help to me.

Comment: Just say, \SepMark{-} works, not \SepMark{--}